# CURL not grabbing. What is alternet of this function?

Tags: php, curl

I wanna make a script which will show reverse ip of a site. For this i am going to use a 3rd party website. So that my script is :

```
<?php
$ip='http://viewdns.info/reverseip/?host=barnesandnoble.com';
$useragent='Mozilla/5.0 (BlackBerry; U; BlackBerry 9700; pt) AppleWebKit/534.8+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0.0.546 Mobile Safari/534.8+';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $ip);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);
$file = curl_exec($ch);
echo ($file); //this is for testing that files are getting or not
?>
```

But this is not returning anything. Is my code error ? or CURL can't get this kinds of web page ?

Comment: Why dont you do  `echo curl_error($ch);` and see what it's saying first? Post the error in an edit...

Comment: nothing executing. just add this line before `$file = curl_exec($ch);`

Comment: Have you tried from your terminal? Try it on your command line first. If it works then something's wrong in your PHP code. Otherwise, there's something else going on.

e.g.
`curl 'http://viewdns.info/reverseip/?host=barnesandnoble.com'`

Comment: @ArdyDedase , It's problem in this url. because i have used another link and that worked. But just simply replace this url. And don't get any result.